# creating jar file on dalvik machine

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I am trying to create jar file from .class file with the following commands.

```
$ javac Foo.java
$ dx --dex --output=foo.jar Foo.class
```

it returns me an error that

```
/usr/bin/dx : unrecognized parameter:  [1]
(use -help to get usage information)
```

it seems like I should set .bashrc but I am not sure what to edit in it. any suggestions?

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/l/dx there's a dx tool that has nothing to do with android (and /usr/bin/dx is a likely place it could live)... looks like you've got the wrong binary (if not the wrong tool completely).

Comment: how can I can I create the jar file then?

Comment: Use the "dx" tool from the Android SDK instead.

Comment: solved by reinstalling tomcat. it seems @mah 's answer worked for me.